# Python version of tf functions

Tags: python, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to transform a velocity from one frame to another. I want to use the transformVector3 function as mentioned in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Using%20Published%20Transforms). Since it requires a StampedVector I am trying to convert the datatype using the function [tf::vector3StampedMsgtoTF](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a091bf046c418be5e6604c1b025e1ff41). I am writing my node in Python but I cannot find the Python version of the above tf functions anywhere.

Any help will be much appreciated.

ps. Does using tf2 avoid the explicit conversion of a geometry message to TF datatypes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258527/python-version-of-tf-functions/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about the website's documentation, but you can find the code for the python implementation of tf [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf/src/tf/listener.py), and it's easy enough to look for vector3.

Alternatively, if you open up a REPL, it's easy to see what functions are available. In ipython, start by importing the listener: `from tf import TransformListener`. Then type `TransformListener.` (don't forget the trailing period) and hit tab. You'll get a list of all possible completions. Pick the one you want to know more about, and type `help(TransformListener.transformVector3)`. Voila - there's your documentation.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1